# Istio 503:s between (Public) Gateway and Service

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I've been playing around with my Istio cluster configuration and I've ended up in a state I can't debug my way out of.

I have the SDS+Gateway with a public IP configured. I have deployed the Istio HelloWorld app on port 5000. I can:

- exec into `istio-proxy` on the `helloworld-[rnd]` pod and `curl localhost:5000/hello` - this works fine
- check with `istioctl proxy-config cluster` (and such) from https://istio.io/docs/ops/troubleshooting/network-issues/ and https://istio.io/docs/ops/troubleshooting/proxy-cmd/ — all report OK to everything, SYNC:ed and such
- I can do `kubectl exec istio-ingressgateway-[rnd] /bin/bash` and then `curl helloworld.mynamespace:5000/hello` successfully (it returns `Hello version: v2 ...`

But I can't make the ingressgateway actually return anything but 503 when querying its publicly bound IP. If I query without the `/hello` path, it returns `404` instead, so it's obviously trying to route to the `helloworld` service/deployment and failing.

So I'm in the state where I can actually contact my `helloworld` service from the Istio Ingress Gateway, when asking the gateway itself `curl localhost/hello -i`, or from ourside the network `curl -i http://35.x.y.z/hello` I always get `503 Service Unavailable Back`

I don't have any DestinationRule nor Policy applying to `helloworld`, and I have Istio in strict mTLS.

I could previously today access (other) services via the ingress gateway, but then I started cleaning things up (to the point when I only have the helloworld service VirtualService+Gateway and no others), and now it doesn't work. It should be possible to debug.

What is wrong?

Not related (that I can tell):

- [Kubernetes Istio ingress gateway responds with 503 always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638780/kubernetes-istio-ingress-gateway-responds-with-503-always) (I don't have clusterIP: None)
- [Accessing service using istio ingress gives 503 error when mTLS is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160215/accessing-service-using-istio-ingress-gives-503-error-when-mtls-is-enabled?rq=1) (after `k exec -c istio-proxy helloworld-[rnd] -- curl http://localhost:15000/logging?level=true`, the `istio-proxy` envoy doesn't receive any calls from `istio-ingressgateway` at all; the traffic never leaves the ingress pod, unlike this question)
- I have CNI + GKE Network Policy enabled (but turning it off didn't help) and a Calico-allow-all rule didn't help, so it should not be this; also, I can curl from ingressgateway, so there's connectivity
- https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/samples/helloworld — config

Answer (score 4):

First of all to use curl with SDS gateway You need to use it as described in Istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/).

```
$ curl -v -HHost:httpbin.example.com \
--resolve httpbin.example.com:$SECURE_INGRESS_PORT:$INGRESS_HOST \
--cacert httpbin.new.example.com/2_intermediate/certs/ca-chain.cert.pem \
https://httpbin.example.com:$SECURE_INGRESS_PORT/status/418
```

```
...
HTTP/2 418
...
-=[ teapot ]=-

   _...._
 .'  _ _ `.
| ."` ^ `". _,
\_;`"---"`|//
  |       ;/
  \_     _/
    `"""`
```

---

Secondly according to [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/) documentation using strict mTLS (mutual TLS) authentication policy requires both services to be running TLS communication. In Your case You are trying to access plain text (HTTP) service with Istio that is using TLS. This causes mutual TLS configuration conflict.

You can verify that with `istioctl` command in [this](https://istio.io/faq/security/#check-policy) section of documentation:

> The  [`istioctl`](https://istio.io/docs/reference/commands/istioctl)  command provides an option for this purpose. You can do:
>
> ```
> $ istioctl authn tls-check $CLIENT_POD httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local
> ```
>
> ```
> HOST:PORT                                  STATUS     SERVER     CLIENT     AUTHN POLICY        DESTINATION RULE
> httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local:8000     OK         mTLS       mTLS       default/            default/istio-system
> ```
>
> Where  `$CLIENT_POD`  is the ID of one of the client service’s pods.
>
> Refer to  [Verify mutual TLS configuration](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/mutual-tls/#verify-mutual-tls-configuration)  for more information.

**To resolve this issue mTLS has to be turned off for this service so that Istio accepts connection from plain text to TLS services. Follow this [guide](https://istio.io/faq/security/#accessing-non-istio-services) to create destination rule that allows non TLS communication for specified service**

To confirm that this is causing this issue You can temporarily enable [Permissive](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authz-permissive/) mode.

---

**Edit:**

From the link you provided in the last deployment file `helloworld.yaml` there is no `targetPort` and this is why nginx is unreachable.

This is how it should look:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    name: http
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: helloworld
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-v1
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        version: v1
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: docker.io/istio/examples-helloworld-v1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent #Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld-v2
  labels:
    version: v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        version: v2
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: docker.io/istio/examples-helloworld-v2
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent #Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

Comment: In this case, my problem was that repeated reconfigurations of Istio causes the whole service mesh to lock up https://gist.github.com/haf-afa/29d904cd9f7fad6aad22c481bc9c7e9e — not until the cluster is reset does an identical configuration yield responses. Or in other words; 1) configure hello world, 2) verify it works OK, 3) configure it differently, 4) you get 503, 5) go back to 1)'s configuration, still 503's

Comment: @Henrik There is an error in istio/helloworld sample. Check my edited answer for solution. It should fix 503 errors.