# Translating Ingress resource to Istio VirtualService or ServiceEntry

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I have an application with an Ingress resource shown below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}-stateful
  labels: 
    app: oxauth
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/ssl-services: "oxtrust"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/identity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream: "error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504"
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ . | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /identity
            backend:
              serviceName: oxtrust
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /idp
            backend:
              serviceName: oxshibboleth
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /passport
            backend:
              serviceName: oxpassport
              servicePort: 8090
```

I would like to translate that into a `VirtualService` to be used by Istio gateway. But once I do that the service `oxpassport` always returns a `503` error in the logs. That means the deployment can't be reached.

Below is the `Service` definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-15T18:21:12Z"
  labels:
    app: oxpassport
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kk
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.1.0_01
    helm.sh/chart: oxpassport-1.0.0
  name: oxpassport
  namespace: test
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.111.71.120
  ports:
  - name: tcp-oxpassport
    port: 8090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8090
  selector:
    app: oxpassport
    release: kk
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

And finally the `VS` I am trying to use:

`VirtualService`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: {{ include "istio.fullname" . }}-oxpassport
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  hosts:
    - oxpassport.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
    - {{ .Release.Name }}-global-gtw
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /passport
    rewrite:
      uri: /identity
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oxpassport.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8090
```

`Gateway` snippet:

```
  - port:
      number: 8090
      name: tcp-oxpassport
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - oxpassport.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
```

Things to note:

1. There is a backend app with these labels. And that has it's own VS and it's working:

   ```
    labels: 
       app: oxauth
   ```
2. Oxpassport has a deployment with labels

   ```
     labels: 
        app: oxpassport
   ```

I know it's a long post but it's a blocker for quite some days now. If it is possible, please explain.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like some of your object definitions are Helm templates. Can you post the actual definitions for clarity?

Comment: Have you tried to remove rewrite and leave only match with prefix? Namespace of your service, virtual service and gateway are the same? What is your istio version? If it's 1.5+ then its might be related to mtls, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160215/accessing-service-using-istio-ingress-gives-503-error-when-mtls-is-enabled?rq=1) and [this](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule).

Answer (score 1):

Gateway should be in the same namespace as virtual service, if it´s not in the same namespace as virtual service, you should add it like in below example.

Check the `spec.gateways` section

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-Mongo
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - some-namespace/my-gateway
```

---

In your ingress you have 3 paths then virtual service based on that ingress should look like there

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: {{ include "istio.fullname" . }}-oxpassport
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  hosts:
    - oxpassport.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
  gateways:
    - {{ .Release.Name }}-global-gtw
  http:
  - name: a
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /identity
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oxtrust.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
  - name: b
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /idp
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oxshibboleth.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
  - name: c
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /passport
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oxpassport.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8090
```

---

Cases with answers worth to check when problem 503 appears.

- https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#503-errors-after-setting-destination-rule
- [Accessing service using istio ingress gives 503 error when mTLS is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160215/accessing-service-using-istio-ingress-gives-503-error-when-mtls-is-enabled?rq=1)
- https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#avoid-503-errors-while-reconfiguring-service-routes
- [how to terminate ssl at ingress-gateway in istio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560394/how-to-terminate-ssl-at-ingress-gateway-in-istio)
- [Kubernetes Istio ingress gateway responds with 503 always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638780/kubernetes-istio-ingress-gateway-responds-with-503-always)

---

**EDIT**

---

> Did you consider this nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/identity"?

Missed that /identity app root, you can always rewrite all of them like you did.

> Also, is there a particular reason why we can separate that whole - big - vs into different VS files?

No, you should be able to create seperate smaller virtual services instead of the big one, I just copied the ingress you provided.

Comment: Great. Just a follow up, @jt97 Did you consider this `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/identity"` ?
Also, is there a particular reason why we can separate that whole - big - vs into different VS files?

Comment: @Shammir I changed my answer to answer your questions, check EDIT.